# Perfmon effect on application

Tags: perfmon

Do perfmon counters degrade application performance in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually updating the counters have negligible effects - They're designed to always be updated with minimum impact. Reading/monitoring them can affect performance though, so you may notice differences when you're actively monitoring.

EDIT: Also see [What is the performance hit of Performance Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290634/what-is-the-performance-hit-of-performance-counters)