# The cost of adding custom performance counters

Tags: asp.net, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the performance hit of Performance Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290634/what-is-the-performance-hit-of-performance-counters)

I would like to add a series of custom performance counters to my existing web application.

What kinds of performance impacts and penalties are associated with adding custom performance counters?

Thank you.