# Does activating off-by-default performance counters in ADO.NET carry a performance hit?

Tags: c#, performance

We recently had a production incident which required enabling some off-by-default performance counters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503(v=vs.110).aspx) to help diagnose.

I was wondering if leaving these counters enabled would cause performance degradation?

The answers in [What is the performance hit of Performance Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290634/what-is-the-performance-hit-of-performance-counters) seem to imply that the counters have a very negligible effect, but they make no reference to the 'off-by-default' counters.

If these counters don't carry a performance hit, then why are they off-by-default?

Comment: Because there are 1000's of them, and anyway why waste resources on something which you only need in special circumstances? Even tiny performance hits add up when you start multiplying by large enough numbers...